# How do you stack views on top of each and have them fill their parent in a NativeScript layout?

Tags: nativescript

I would like to have multiple views stacked on top of each other so that each view completely covers the views below it and every view fills the parent container.

As I see it the only layout I can use is `AbsoluteLayout`, since that allows views to cover up other views. But when I put a view in an `AbsoluteLayout` I cannot get it to fill the parent container.

Specifically my layout looks like this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <WebView />
    <WebView />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Whenever I launch the app and zoom into the WebView the view starts to grow indefinitely and crashes my phone. I would like `AbsoluteLayout` to fill its parent and each `WebView` to fill the size of the `AbsoluteLayout`.

I cannot reliably get the dimensions of any view in NativeScript and I cannot watch for changes in these dimensions. What I have been doing is polling for changes and hard-coding numbers to calculate the size of the `WebView`s.

Comment: Couldn't you just use relative values for this? So `AbsoluteLayout{width: 100%; height: 100%}` along with `WebView{width: 100%; height: 100%}`

Comment: This is an experimental feature and relative values don't make so much sense inside of an absolute layout. Like `100%` width placed `100%` down and `100%` to the right?